# Postgres function FOR IN SELECT LOOP scaling

Tags: postgresql, function, for-loop

I am trying to understand how loops actually work inside a postgres function.

The question is, when a FOR LOOP is run with a SELECT query like this:

```
FOR v_tmp_pk IN SELECT user_pk
                        FROM users_table
                        WHERE enterprise_id = in_enterprise_id
                            AND
                             category_id = in_category_id
                            AND status = 0 ORDER BY user_pk LOOP
```

Are all the results of query loaded at once or are the results paged and returned like `psql` would return them? The actual FOR LOOP will be run for a small number of iterations and will then exit.

```
(...)
DECLARE
        v_user_pks int[];
        v_tmp_pk int;
BEGIN


FOR v_tmp_pk IN SELECT user_pk
                        FROM users_table
                        WHERE enterprise_id = in_enterprise_id
                            AND
                             category_id = in_category_id
                            AND status = 0 ORDER BY user_pk LOOP

    -- Try to get a lock on the record
    IF pg_try_advisory_xact_lock(v_tmp_pk) THEN

        -- Push in the array we are tracking
        v_user_pks = array_append(v_user_pks, v_tmp_pk);
    end if;

    -- If we have collected enough records, then come out of the loop
   EXIT WHEN array_length(v_user_pks, 1) = in_count;
end loop;

-- Do more things
(...)
```

I am trying to understand how this type of loop will scale. How will the performance be different - If the table that is being queried from has a few 100 valid results vs a million results.

Would it load all the results at once and then iterate over them or would it iterate over them in chunks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL uses a cursor internally to process such a loop. That means that the results are calculated row by row, and there is no danger of an internal buffer overflowing.